# css media query dosent work on 1200px large screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

i have a problem with media queries, the code works fine until it touches 1200 px(large screen) the fourth and fifth boxes are attached.
the same thing happens when I try to put 6 boxes per row.
i tried several solutions but none worked
how i can fix it?
thx

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  #pic {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    width: calc(1/3*100% - (1 - 1/3)*10px);
    background: #46B980;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(-n+3) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
{
  #pic {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    width: calc(1/4*100% - (1 - 1/4)*10px);
    background: #46B980;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(-n+4) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)
{
  #pic {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    width: calc(1/5*100% - (1 - 1/5)*10px);
    background: #46B980;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
  }

  #pic:nth-child(5) {
    margin-right: 0;

  }
  #pic:nth-child(-n+5) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
      <div id="pic">f</div>
    <div id="pic"></div>
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="pic"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to change the code a bit. The only line that should be affected is the **2nd** media query. Currently, it is:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { ... }
```

This should be changed to:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

This seemed to work for me.

*Note: You'll have to open the code snippet in full screen to see the effects*

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  #pic {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    width: calc(1/3*100% - (1 - 1/3)*10px);
    background: #46B980;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(-n+3) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) /* this was the change */
{
  #pic {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    width: calc(1/4*100% - (1 - 1/4)*10px);
    background: #46B980;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #pic:nth-child(-n+4) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)
{
  #pic {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    width: calc(1/5*100% - (1 - 1/5)*10px);
    background: #46B980;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
  }

  #pic:nth-child(5) {
    margin-right: 0;

  }
  #pic:nth-child(-n+5) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
      <div id="pic">f</div>
    <div id="pic"></div>
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="pic"></div>
```

Comment: nope.. dosent work for me

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. Let me look at it a bit more.

Comment: I edited the response, take a look at it to see what I did.